# How to append more than 1 optional query parameters in URL and then get records based on those 2 parameters?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently my simple filter allows me to get the images either in ascending or descending order. Now I'm trying to make it so I can get the images from today/this week/this month in ascending or descending order AKA apply the 2 filters simultaneously.

The problem is that I can't get the second query parameter to stick at the end of the URL. When I'm on `www.example.com` and click the ascending `<a>` element my URL becomes `www.example.com/?order=asc`. Then when I click the today `<a>` element my URL becomes `www.example.com/?time=today` but I want it to become `www.example.com/?order=asc?time=today` so then I can get the time through my request.

I'm also not sure how exactly would my query look like when trying to combine these 2 filters which are optimal and might not even be present in the URL but I guess I'll figure that out once I'm actually able to append both the filters to my URL.

HTML

```
<ul class='home-filters'>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <li><a class='placeholderA' href='/'>Descending</a></li>
        <li><a class='placeholderA' href='?order=asc'>Ascending</a></li>
        <li><a class='placeholderA' href='/?time=today'>Today</a></li>
        <li><a class='placeholderA' href='?time=week'>This Week</a></li>
        <li><a class='placeholderA' href='?time=month'>This Month</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

PagesController

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', $request->get('order') ?? 'desc')->get();

        return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
    }
```

Comment: `www.example.com/?order=asc?time=today` is incorrect, you want `www.example.com/?order=asc&time=today` with an ampersand

Comment: I see, but how do I append the second query parameter to the URL that is either www.example.com or www.example.com/?order=asc?

Comment: I am not a Laravel user, but I imagine you would have to put a variable in your template for the `href` of the `a` tag, and then do some conditional logic to decide what you should put in the query string of the url.

Comment: You may be interested in https://github.com/Kyslik/laravel-filterable

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do basic filtering myself so I don't really wanna use libraries that do it for me.

Comment: I haven't said you are supposed to `composer install` it, but take a look at it (`src` directory) :) and there is some info in the readme for more... Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all direct children of ul tags should be li tags.

What you are trying to do can be easily accomplish by just using a form like the following.

```
<form action="url" method="GET">
    <input type="radio" name="order" value="asc" checked>Asceding
    <input type="radio" name="order" value="desc">Descending
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="any" checked>Anytime
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="today">Today
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="week">This week
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="month">This month
    <button>
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: He is making a filter, hence there should be checkboxes instead of radio buttons

Comment: @FahadIqbalAhmadKhan he asked how to add 2 get params so it is just an example for the shake of simplicity on how he can do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the request URL instead for the `href` values, and then scan and filter optional query parameters in controller.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests)